# Adding multiple(extra) white spaces to span using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been looking for this question around and still didn't find an answer. I know how to add a single space with the append method in jQuery but don't know how to add multiple spaces.

Example:

```
<div id="#myDiv"> hey? <span class="space"></span> my name<span class="space"></span> is coding enthusiast<span class="space"></span> .....</di>
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
Hey          my name        is coding enthusiast        ......
```

I have tried Jquery append, it gives me nothing like that.

```
 //1st try 
 $('space').append("      ");
 //2nd try
 $('space').append("&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp");
 //2nd try output: hey&nbsp&nbsp&nbspmy name&nbsp&nbsp&nbspis coding enthusiast&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp....
```

I feel like I am missing something small. Any ideas?

Edit: Had a typo in my code's question which misled some people when answering:

```
    //1st try 
     $('.space').append("      ");
     //2nd try
     $('.space').append("&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp");
     //2nd try output: hey&nbsp&nbsp&nbspmy name&nbsp&nbsp&nbspis coding enthusiast&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed, forgot semicolon, Thanks to Jake's comment(which he deleted already), I could fix this issue.

```
  $('.space').append("&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;");
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not selecting your elements correctly and add semicolon. Try this:

```
$('.space').append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `.` to specify you're selecting by a class, and add a semicolon after `nbsp` (as Jake Opena pointed out.)

```
$('.space').append("&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;");
```

Comment: my bad, typo when posting the question. :) thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 1):

A different approach could be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/fvLxxwa4/

Use this styling for .space:

```
.space {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```